# Do nutrition fact labels include the nutritional content of wasted (unreachable) food?

Tags: nutrition

Many packaged foods are in containers or bags which result in a significant amount of the food being left behind in their packaging (soup at the bottom of the can, melted cheese left on the pan from pizza, etc). Are food packagers aware of this waste and if so, are they taking it into account for the nutritional facts on their packages.

For example, if a frozen pizza manufacturer studied consumers preparing and eating the pizza, and determined that 100 calories get left behind on the pan, on average, are they subtracting that from the nutritional facts, or does the consumer have to do this mental math to properly estimate caloric intake?

Comment: What's your research show?

Comment: Welcome to Health, Afforess! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Please document your own research on this, like @Graham said. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: @GrahamChiu The FDA guidelines are fairly large, but from brief research, it seems that manufacturers develop the nutritional facts either from previously established sources (other packaged food inputs to their product) or laboratory sampling. As a consumer, it's hard to tell which products nutrition are from samples or aggregate. Sampling to determine nutrition only opens more questions, do they test food the same way consumers do, leaving waste, or other unknown methods? https://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/LabelingNutrition/ucm063113.htm

Comment: Give a specific example that confuses you.

Comment: Of course they include the entire contents. I have no problem getting all the soup out of the can and all the cheese off the pan, and even if I did all the manufacturers can assume is I might get utensils to  scrape it all off and eat it. What on earth other numbers could they piublish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, they do not take waste and left-overs into account.

Nutrition information is by serving or package content:

> The first place to start when you look at the Nutrition Facts label is the serving size and the number of servings in the package. **Serving sizes are standardized to make it easier to compare similar foods**; they are provided in familiar units, such as cups or pieces, followed by the metric amount, e.g., the number of grams.
>
> The size of the serving on the food package influences the number of calories and all the nutrient amounts listed on the top part of the label. **Pay attention to the serving size, especially how many servings there are in the food package. Then ask yourself, "How many servings am I consuming"?** (e.g., 1/2 serving, 1 serving, or more) In the sample label, one serving of macaroni and cheese equals one cup. If you ate the whole package, you would eat two cups. That doubles the calories and other nutrient numbers, including the %Daily Values as shown in the sample label.
>
> <sup>[FDA.org](https://www.fda.gov/Food/LabelingNutrition/ucm274593.htm#serving_size), *Emphasis Mine*</sup>

Comment: This answer confuses me more. The first sentence has the text: *in the package*, but the rest of the paragraph is instructional, not say, rules or guidelines, so the context is unclear. The second paragraph only says *on the package*, which does not answer the question.

Comment: @Afforess **"in the package"** are the magic words you were looking for. The rest just explains why FDA regulation labels are confusing and why they need explanation and what that explanation is. You read on that label what you paid for. What you eat of that or how much of that you waste is your business. Also, "significant amounts": these kcal numbers should serve *you* as a rough estimate and guideline. If you aim for the last 33.3 kcal or so left in a soup can, you're  overdoing the math already.

Comment: @Afforess To explain: If it says 100g serving contains x kcal, it means that 100g contain x kcal and if the whole product has a weight of 300g, 3x kcal is contained in it. The serving is how much they think one serves and is irrelevant of whether you eat up your plate or not.

Comment: @Afforess I don't know how much more clear it could be than nutrition in a serving size and number of servings in the package.

Comment: @pararazzo - why would the nutrition facts and serving sizes be clear? If you take the food out and weight it, the amount will differ from the package listing - you can't rely on the nutrition facts. That's what this question is all about.

Comment: @Afforess No way.  That would be false advertising.   If it says serving size 4 oz and 3 serving per container it will be 12 oz total.  They properly report nutrition for a common single serving as that is more meaningful than for total contents.

Comment: @paparazzo I am not talking about false advertising, nor malice, nor incompetence. I am talking about the margin of error (packages that say 4oz and have 3.9oz) and wasted food by consumers. I don't know how you came to the alternate conclusion this was about accuracy - the title says "waste" right in it.

Comment: @Afforess I can't help you.  You don't make sense to me.   Weigh contents, loss in cooking ....